# What does the &^= operator do?

Tags: go, operators

I came across [this line](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/mem_windows.go#L48) in the source code for the Go language itself:

```
small &^= 4096 - 1
```

I have never seen the `&^=` operator before (either in Go or in C) - what does it do?

Comment: It's the assignment version of "bit clear". See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators

Comment: Here's a [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/Fiui69Kt6n) that may help.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have mentioned, `&^` is the "bit clear" (`AND NOT`) operator, and `a &^= b` means `a = (a &^= b)`

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Fiui69Kt6n):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var x int64 = 0xdeadbeefface
    fmt.Printf("   x = %064b %012x\n", x, x)

    var y int64 = 0xffff0000
    fmt.Printf("   y = %064b %012x\n", y, y)

    x &^= y
    fmt.Printf("x&^y = %064b %012x\n", x, x)
}
```

```
   x = 0000000000000000110111101010110110111110111011111111101011001110 deadbeefface
   y = 0000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111110000000000000000 0000ffff0000
x&^y = 0000000000000000110111101010110100000000000000001111101011001110 dead0000face
```

### And `small &^= 4096 - 1`?

Since `4095 - 1 == 0b0000111111111111`, it would mean "set the 12 least significant bits of a number to zero".

```golang
func main() {
    small := 0xdeadbeefface
    fmt.Printf("             small : %064b %012x\n", small, small)
    small &^= 4096 - 1
    fmt.Printf("small &^= 4096 - 1 : %064b %012x\n", small, small)
}
```

```
             small : 0000000000000000110111101010110110111110111011111111101011001110 deadbeefface
small &^= 4096 - 1 : 0000000000000000110111101010110110111110111011111111000000000000 deadbeeff000
```